# Which version of Ubuntu for Mac?

Tags: mac, downloads

The download page only mentions desktop pcs, so what version do I get for a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the Desktop version (Desktop refers to any computer that isn't a server), and if you have a newer mac, the 64-bit version.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

If you're just trying it out, you might want the latest version -- 13.04 for all the shiny new features.  Otherwise, if you're looking for something to put on your computer and Just Get Work Done, I would recommend 12.04.

Answer (score -1):

A mac is a desktop pc isn't (desktop as in desktop or laptop)?  So get the desktop version.

Comment: see here: http://www.tuaw.com/2009/09/07/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-linux-on-a-mac-its-easy-and-free/